# Sinatra: rendering snippets (partials)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm following along with an O'Reilly book that's building a twitter clone with Sinatra. As Sinatra doesn't have 'partials' (in the way that Rails does), the author creates his own 'snippets' that work like partials. I understand that this is fairly common in Sinatra.

Anyways, inside one of his snippets (see the first one below) he calls another snippet text_limiter_js (which is copied below). Text_limiter_js is basically a javascript function.

If you look at the javascript function in text_limiter_js, you'll notice that it takes two parameters. I don't understand where these parameters are coming from because they're not getting passed in when text_limiter_js is rendered inside the other snippet.

I'm not sure if I've given enough information/code for someone to help me understand this, but if you can, please explain.

```
=snippet :'/snippets/text_limiter_js'
%h2.comic What are you doing?
%form{:method => 'post', :action => '/update'}
  %textarea.update.span-15#update{:name => 'status', :rows => 2, :onKeyDown => "text_limiter($('#update'), $('#counter'))"}
  .span-6
    %span#counter
      140
    characters left
  .prepend-12
    %input#button{:type => 'submit', :value => 'update'}
```

text_limiter_js.haml

```
:javascript
  function text_limiter(field,counter_field) {
    limit = 139;
    if (field.val().length > limit) 
      field.val(field.val().substring(0, limit));
    else
      counter_field.text(limit - field.val().length);
  }
```

Comment: actually, this is probably a stupid question. The function likely gets called from somewhere else, even if it's rendered onto the page from the containing snippet, so the parameters will be passed from wherever it's called. stupid me.

Comment: you should then close the question or make this the answer.

Comment: Cloning Internet applications with Ruby